# remove NumberLong from time when running

Tags: mongodb

How to remove **NumberLong** when running `db.adminCommand("top").totals["app.fc_set"].queries.time` is there any option that can be used so it does not show up?

```
{
    "totals" : {
        "note" : "all times in microseconds",
        "admin" : {
            .......
        },
        "app.fc_set" : {
            "total" : {
                "time" : NumberLong("47266389985250"),
                "count" : 5998426181
            }
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: please explain your use case a bit more. Do you want to change the underlying data type of the field or do you just want to change the apperance? And the question is: Why?

Comment: just change the apperance